# How to get url of GET response in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, get, ionic-framework, response

Dear stackoverflow users/angular jedi masters, I am in a little trouble.
I need to get URL of GET response, but can't find how to do this in a 26+ hours.

The code that I am using works fine, I am sending GET request to server, than the server responds with 302 and sends me 200. Now I need to parse response URL. I can see the url value in chrome debugging tool, but currently don't know how to do this, without inapp browser. Headers and data sections in the response doesn't contain the needed url.

```
function get_code(credentials, callback) {
    data = {merge(credentials, {some_data_here}}
    $http.get(url, {params: data}).then(function(response) {
        callback(response);
    }, function(data) {
        console.log("Houston we have a problem!");
    });
}
```

i have used inappbrowser like this

```
var ref = window.open(url);
ref.addEventListener('loadstart', function(event) {
    if(event.url.indexOf(constant_part_of_url_here) > -1) {
        code = (event.url).split("code=")[1];
        ref.close();
    }
});
```

But this solution seems not perfect to me.
Thank you.

Comment: use a wrapper like `callback({url: url, res: response});`

Comment: url value gets response value from $http.get() and res is undefined
@dendavis

Answer (score 0):

```
<h3>Parse URL using AngularJS</h3>

url: <input type="text" ng-model="url" value="" style="width:780px;">

<ul>
    <li>href = {{parser.href}}</li>
    <li>protocol = {{parser.protocol}}</li>
    <li>host = {{parser.host}}</li>
    <li>hostname = {{parser.hostname}}</li>
    <li>port = {{parser.port}}</li>
    <li>pathname = {{parser.pathname}}</li>
    <li>hash = {{parser.hash}}</li>
    <li>search = {{parser.search}}</li>
</ul>
```

**AngularJS Controller**

```
function AppCtrl($scope) {

    $scope.$watch('url', function () {
        $scope.parser.href = $scope.url;
    });

    $scope.init = function () {
        $scope.parser = document.createElement('a');
        $scope.url = window.location;
    }

}
```

Comment: that doesn't help :(